# How do I display a tree view based on this given database data?

Tags: sql, mysql, tree

The table looks like:

```
id | title | parent | depth |
---+-------+--------+-------+
 1 | blah  |  0     |  0
---+-------+--------+-------+
 2 | blah  |  0     |  0
---+-------+--------+-------+
 3 | blah  |  0     |  0
---+-------+--------+-------+
 4 | blah  |  2     |  1
---+-------+--------+-------+
 5 | blah  |  2     |  1
---+-------+--------+-------+
 6 | blah  |  5     |  2
---+-------+--------+-------+
```

I want to take that data and output it into a tree like view. Similar to:

```
1 - blah
2 - blah
    4 - blah
    5 - blah
        6 - blah
3 - blah
```

Someone suggested I use the query:

```
SELECT title, depth FROM table ORDER BY parent, id
```

I could then use the `depth` to create the whitespace on the left and format the tree. This works up until I use HTML. I want to be able to format it nicely in valid HTML and then style it with CSS, etc...

Using just the depth, I can't think of a way to wrap the comments in a `div class="parent/child"` type structure.

How can I format the data?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<ul>` in HTML, with a `<li>` for each item. Every time you increase in depth compared to the last item, add one `<ul>` to the current `<li>` instead of closing it. If the current depth is lower than the previous, close off one `</ul></li>` pair for each level of depth difference.

Comment: P.S. [Do not use div elements](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#semanticmarkup) unless you must.

Comment: I've tried to implement your solution in but I'm not getting it right. It's missing the closing tags. http://codepad.org/bpkvcJbP

Answer (score -1):

if you already have figured out how to get the depth of an entry (or the number of ancestors that is), then you could try the following:

css code:

```
.tab {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

rendered html code:

```
<p>
    <span class="">1 - blah</span><br />
    <span class="">2 - blah</span><br />
    <span class="tab">4 - blah</span><br />
    <span class="tab">5 - blah</span><br />
    <span class="tab tab">6 - blah</span><br />
    <span class="">3 - blah</span>
</p>
```

and you'll use your logic to determine how many "tab" to add to the span's class attribute. each "tab" you add puts that line 20 more pixels to the right.

Comment: actually, phrogz' answer is better, since it uses semantically correct html. after all, these are lists we're dealing with here.